# Grouping by keywords in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(barcode), location, AVG(updated), MAX(updated), COUNT(rejects)  FROM (
SELECT order_reference AS barcode,
    mth.location AS location,
    (bigint(to_timestamp(NOW()))) - (bigint(to_timestamp(mth.last_update_ts))) AS updated,
row_number() over(partition by order_reference order by mth.last_update_ts asc) rw,
r.id AS rejects
FROM zz_liab_visionlabs.sales_order_header soh
INNER JOIN zz_liab_visionlabs.manufacturing_tracking_history mth
    ON soh.id = mth.sales_order_header_id
INNER JOIN zz_liab_visionlabs.reject r
    ON soh.id = r.sales_order_header_id
) t
where t.rw=1 and location not like '%Dispatch%'
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY Count(barcode)
limit 300;
```

[Visualization][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlQOa.png

I would like to group locations by for example keywords. Like locations containing word "Generating" together and ones containing "Engraving" together etc.

Comment: Do you have a field that contain keywords or tags ?

Comment: Hi. I don't know if you seen the visualization above but there is only that field location which includes keywords but those would need to extracted as third word separated by dots.